# Is it possible to set width and height in % in jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, drupal, slideshow

I am working in drupal..I have made a slide show using jquery,But the images shows different sizes in different browsers. Is it possible to set the width and height in %

```
<script src="http://test/sites/js/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('#ft').jqFancyTransitions({
    effect: 'zipper', // wave, zipper, curtain
    width: 682, // width of panel
    height: 268, // height of panel
    strips: 20, // number of strips
    delay: 2500, // delay between images in ms
    stripDelay: 50, // delay beetwen strips in ms
    titleOpacity: 0.7, // opacity of title
    titleSpeed: 1000, // speed of title appereance in ms
    position: 'alternate', // top, bottom, alternate, curtain
    direction: 'fountainAlternate', // left, right, alternate, random, fountain, fountainAlternate
    navigation: false, // prev and next navigation buttons
    links: false // show images as links
});
```

Comment: Have you tried?  e.g. using `width: "30%", height: "20%"`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
width : screen.width * (desired percentage/100),
height: screen.height * (dsired percentage/100),
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see that you can directly in the plugin code, however you could omit the width and height lines and use css to style the relevant images from a stylesheet  and set the dimensions in a percentage there

Comment: width and height are specified in jqFancyTransitions.1.8.min.js. If that is removed from there then the slide show dosen't appers

Answer (score 0):

```
// set panel
        $('#'+el.id).css({
            'background-image':'url('+img[el.id][0]+')',
            'width': params.width,
            'height': params.height,
            'position': 'relative',
            'background-position': 'top left'
            });
```

For example:

```
// set panel
        $('#'+el.id).css({
            'background-image':'url('+img[el.id][0]+')',
            'width': a%,
            'height': b%,
            'position': 'relative',
            'background-position': 'top left'
            });
```

This is the related code from jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js

You may try to replace the `params.width` and `params.height` values to percentages not all of them but under `//set panel` where the css is assigned on your parameters. However those two variables also used in other places in the code. You may never know what they effect unless you try it.

Comment: In jqFancyTransitions.1.8.min.js the styles are specified like this. $.fn.jqFancyTransitions.defaults={width:500,height:332,strips:10,delay:5000,stripDelay:50,titleOpacity:0.7,titleSpeed:1000,position:'alternate',direction:'fountainAlternate',effect:'',navigation:false,links:false};})(jQuery);

Comment: Yes and they are default values. As you see above default values are being replaced by using `.css()` with your parameters. Assign them again `width: 682` and `height: 268` in `$('#ft').`but change the values under `// set panel` to make them your desired percentage

Comment: I changed set panel, but all images are displayed one after another...   set panel
               $('#'+el.id).css({
                       'background-image':'url('+img[el.id][0]+')',
                       'width': 100%,
                       'height': 50%,
                       'position': 'relative',
                       'background-position': 'top left'
                       });

Comment: Is it possible to change these values of width and height  to%      // default values
       $.fn.jqFancyTransitions.defaults = {        
               width: 500, // width of panel
               height: 332, // height of panel
               strips: 10, // number of strips
               delay: 5000, // delay between images in ms
                            
       };
       
})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how changing to `% width & height` will make your images having the same size on different browsers.

Defining the `width & height` in `px` is your best choice to have same size across all browsers.

But if you really want to, you should modify that function parameters and set something like this:

```
   $.....
   $width: '80%', // width of panel
   $height: '60%', // height of panel
   $.....
```